# Regex, detect no spaces in the string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

This is my current regex check:

`const validPassword = (password) => password.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.\S)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}$/);`

I have a check for at least 1 letter and 1 number and at least 6 characters long. However I also want to make sure that there are no spaces anywhere in the string.

So far I'm able to enter in 6 character strings with spaces included :([image]

Found this answer here, but for some reason in my code it's passing.

[What is the regular expression for matching that contains no white space in between text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020760/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-matching-that-contains-no-white-space-in-betw)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\S{6,}$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\d)` - 1 digit (at least)
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`  - at least 1 letter
- `\S{6,}` - 6 or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string anchor

With a [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) in mind, you may revamp the pattern into

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])\S{6,}$/
```

Comment: That's a great explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Geez Regex is always over my head, hardly run into a case where I have to use it.